# Spl_Auto_register not loading class properly

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

I'm trying to learn about spl_autoload_register().
My index.php is under document root, my MyClass.php is put under document root /MyProject/MyClass/MyClass.php
Here's my index.php

```
<?php

define('CLASSDIR', 'mylib');
define('BASEPATH',  @realpath( dirname (__FILE__).'/../').'/'.CLASSDIR);

spl_autoload_register(null, false);
spl_autoload_extensions('.php');

// PSR-0 provided autoloader.
function autoLoader($className){

    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= BASEPATH.'/'.str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
    require $fileName;
}

spl_autoload_register('autoLoader');

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->test();
?>
```

Here's my Class: MyClass.php

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\MyClass;

class MyClass{

    public function __contruct(){
        echo('weird');
    }

    function test(){
        echo 'issue';
    }
}?>
```

Here's the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method MyClass::test() in /path/to/file/index.php on line 26
```

So, I'm assuming it found the class (since it didn't complain)? But the messages 'weird' and 'issue' are not displayed. Telling me that the constructor didn't fire.

Comment: Is that the only error you're getting?

Comment: Also, are your classes stored in `mylib` ? Because you've defined it to point to `@realpath( dirname (__FILE__).'/../').'/'.CLASSDIR`, yet have the file located at: `document root /MyProject/MyClass/MyClass.php`

Comment: @dbh Yes, this is the only error I'm getting. If I change the class name to new MyClassA(), it throws error at that point itself. So I'm thinking that MyClass is being found and instantiated successfully. And that confuses me, because test() should be accessible if that's the case.

Comment: @dbh I used CLASSDIR earlier, because I wanted to keep the class files  outside the document root. And that didn't work, so I thought moving it into the document root might help. But nope, it didn't.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve seems simple - Have the class files with proper namespaces (PSR-0) outside document root. Have index.php and other 'user-facing' files inside docroot. Have the spl_autload_register load my class files automatically like it's supposed to. I'm new to spl_autoload_register, so if you know of a better way to do this, I'm all ears.

Comment: does it echo weird out at all?

Comment: @dbh nope, it doesn't. And hence 'weird' :)

Comment: The way I do it is use the `__autoload()` function, I'll post an answer shortly

Comment: @dbh But isn't __autoload supposed to be deprecated. I got that from here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php and hence decided to go with spl_autoload_register().

Comment: Are you sure that path you are looking your classes at is correct because from the above code you are looking Myclass in mylib whereas they are in MyProject/Myclass

Answer (score 0):

Okay, assuming your class file is located in a seperate folder called `classes` (example)
Structure like this:

```
DOCUMENT_ROOT/
    ->index.php
    ->classes/
        ->Myclass/
            ->Myclass.php
```

Somewhere on your `index.php` You'd have something looking like this:

```
<?php 
DEFINE('__BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

require_once('load.php');
?>
```

Now your `load.php` file should have the [`__autoload()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) function in there, looking something like this:

```
// Auto load function to load all the classes as required
function __autoload($class_name) {
    $filename = ucfirst($class_name) . '.php';
    $file = __BASE . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'classes/' . ucfirst($class_name) . $filename;

    // First file (model) doesnt exist
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        // include class
        require $file;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you'd like to do it with `spl_autoload_register()`, you'd have something similar to this in your `load.php`

```
// Auto load function to load all the classes as required
    function load_classes($class_name) {
        $filename = ucfirst($class_name) . '.php';
        $file = __BASE . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'classes/' . ucfirst($class_name) . $filename;

        // First file (model) doesnt exist
        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            // include class
            require $file;
        }
    }

    spl_autoload_register('load_classes');
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Let me try this out and get back to you. I still stick to my previous comment about __autoload being discouraged by PHP in favor of spl_autoload_register. But I'm sure I can benefit from the example above. Will let you know soon.

Comment: not sure why your answer was down voted. Anyway, I finally got around to doing this today and still doesn't work. For the above example, can you please edit your answer to take the classes folder outside the document root, one level up and then show the autoload? For the life of me, I'm not able to figure this simple thing out. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!